# CefSharp old version issue gives notice of upgrade your browser on every website

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, upgrade, cefsharp

i have created a chromium  following online tutorials

```
    using CefSharp;
    using CefSharp.Internals;
    using CefSharp.WinForms;
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(Cef.ChromiumVersion);  

        browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("google.com")
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Size = new Size(600, 600),
            Location = new Point(200, 200),
        };
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
    }
}
```

Every thing is working fine but it shows version
43.0.2357.130

when ever i go to any website it show update notice like google.com trello.com etc etc

Please Guide me how to upgrade latest version of my custom browser

Comment: Upgrade via nuget, the package is https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/

Comment: When you open your `NuGet Package Manger -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`, you'll see that there's an `Updates` panel: open that panel and let the Manager perform the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade you visual studio to 2019
you need to install NuGet Package Manger and search for cefsharp it auto installs every thing